# fwrite php win непонятное поведение

Tags: php

При некоррекном завершении работы пк в файле появляются NULL символы (chr(0)), попытаемся их убрать:

```
$file = 'e:/1.txt';

file_put_contents($file, 'hello'.chr(1).'0df6ac'.chr(0));

$fp = fopen($file, 'r+b');

$str = fread($fp, filesize($file));

$str = strtr($str, [chr(0)=>'']);
echo $str.PHP_EOL;//hello0df6ac

fseek($fp, 0);//указатель в начало
fwrite($fp, $str);

fclose($fp);
```

Ничего не меняется, опытным путём выяснил:
 1. fopen считывает все символы
 2. fwrite как бы "оставляет" старые символы (если к записываемой строке добавить символ это видно)

file_put_contents работает правильно, но т.к. мне нужно открывать файл на чтение с блокировкой, эта функция не подходит

Comment: Подождите, вы открываете файл для чтения с блокировкой и в него пытаетесь записать что то?

Comment: да, данный пример я упростил, тут нет блокировки, но поведение такое же.

Comment: ещё раз `$fp = fopen($file, 'r+b');` и `fwrite($fp, $str);` это же не будет работать даже сокращенно вы открыли фаил для четения,  а надо чтение и запись открывать

Comment: да что с вами такое то? я код для чего привёл, запустить не можете? "r+" - это что по вашему? мануал посмотрим? "'r+' Открывает файл для чтения и записи; помещает указатель в начало файла." https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = strtr($str, [chr(0)=>'']);
```

Вы заменяете нулевой байт на пустую строку. То есть нулевой байт вы вырезаете и новая строка становится короче. И здесь как раз критично важно то что новая строка стала меньше.

Вы делаете `fseek` в начало и пишете новую строку. `fwrite` пишет указанные данные в место файла по текущему смещению. Вы решили, что `fwrite` должен отбросить остальную часть файла? Нет, `fwrite` это делать не должен. Это простое действие записать N байт данных. Вы попросили записать по смещению 0 в файл размером 13 байт новые данные размером 12 байт. Эти 12 байт и были перезаписаны. Тринадцатый байт как был так и остался нетронутым, с ним ничего делать не просили.

Вам необходимо вызвать `ftruncate` где-то. Например, после `fseek` отбросить содержимое файла до 0:

```
fseek($fp, 0);
ftruncate($fp, 0);
```

Либо после записи данных но тогда уже с ненулевым значением `size`.

Comment: да, спасибо, сам только что нашёл эту функцию, именно так, с ним всё работает